# How to run Selenium script on Android?

Tags: android, firefox, selenium-webdriver, adt

I complete selenium webdriver script for Firefox on Windows PC. It works well. 
I try to run the same script on Android phone. 
My environment is Eclipse. I install ADT plugin on Eclipse, but I don't know how to do next.
I also install ADT on my machine. Should I keep working on Eclipse or move to ADT?
I understand ADT is for Android APP development. But I just want to call browser and run script. I don't have any Android APP. I can install firefox on the Android. 
And could I run script on any Android simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Selendroid (http://selendroid.io/)? It is a Selenium implementation for Android that extends the framework to support native Android applications. They even provide a nifty quick start guide: http://selendroid.io/quickStart.html

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I don't try Selendroid yet. Let me try.